# Invoke multiple drag in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

Just wondering how to invoke multiple drag in the iOS simulator. I can obviously do this with a single item, but how do I add to the current drag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't really multitouch in the simulator, but you can add items to a started drag:

Start dragging one item as usual, then hold down the `ctrl` key and (while holding down `ctrl`) release the click from your trackpad. The simulator will drop one virtual finger (represented by a greyish circle) at the last position of your drag and keep the dragged object there. You can then stop holding `ctrl` and continue navigating the app with your cursor and add items to your drag by clicking on them. If you want to resume the drag, just click and hold the circle and continue your drag as before.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/873610647610589184?lang=en)